# Job advertising?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, scope, policy

Is there an appropriate spot on here to advertise a latex-related job/commission? Alternatively, would it be appropriate to privately message some users and invite them to apply for a job/commission? Or would this be generally frowned upon as being not what this site is intended for?

Comment: There are no private messages in the network. Either you post a comment or enter TeX.SX chatroom, but all is public, apart from own chatrooms which have restricted user access, but in this case, the effect of your advertisement would be very limited. How about a newsletter, being distributed via TUG, DANTE etc.?

Comment: By the way: Posting a private job offer etc. is not really fair to users. Anybody should be informed and have the chance to apply/getting involved ;-)

Comment: Oops, didn't realise there was no private messaging system on here. Discard that part of the question. I only suggested it as an alternative if a more public offer wasn't allowed. It is far from ideal.

Comment: If you want to ask particular people and they are package authors, you can probably find contact details in their packages. Since these often go stale, your best bet would be to look on CTAN and check their newest/most recently updated packages for these details.

Comment: @Ulysses: Did you found someone to help you with your thesis? If not you may like to take a look at [my website](http://tobiw.de/en) and contact me ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I just signed up for [freelancer.ca](http://freelancer.ca) **(see edit below for more details)** and basically you can look for freelancers in specific areas to do your "projects", including LaTeX. From what I can see, some of the freelancers seem to have really solid reviews and even have examples of their work. You can also post your "project" and have freelancers bid on it (but stick with the LaTeX tag only; otherwise, you'll end up with a LOT of bids from freelancers who know nothing about it).

As an alternative to this, it really would be nice to have somewhere on here as a "LaTeX-for-hire" job listing forum. The [TUG jobboard](https://www.tug.org/jobboard.html) seems to be pretty dead (no new jobs since July 2014), and [their consultant listing](http://www.tug.org/consultants.html) seems to be mainly geared towards heavy/intense/professional jobs.

As far as I can see, the freelancer website seems to be the best place for getting smaller jobs done (although they can do big ones as well, but I would rather have bigger jobs done by a professional with their own website or an owner of a prominent LaTeX package, etc). There really should be an SE alternative to this for smaller jobs (not for [huge ones](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)) IMO, or at least a LaTeX-specific one.

---

**Edit:** I just finished a project I assigned to someone I hired on there, and he did a pretty good job! There was a *lot* of back-and-forth communication to make sure the TikZ pictures (in my case) came out the way I wanted them to, but the person I hired at least (can't speak for others) worked pretty hard to make sure I was satisfied. There are some PhD students on there, but I just hired a physics grad student.

Also, you don't pay for the entire project at once, you actually just give a small deposit fee first, and don't pay them more until they give you deliverables/updates half way (you can customise this to set more milestones than just halfway too). This is a good thing since you don't have to worry *as much* about money going to waste. Of course, as Johannes said, with freelancers you never know what you'll get, but I think this system helps minimise the risks of that (with the payment structure I mentioned).

Note that this is just *my* experience, but I think if you choose a freelancer wisely you can end up with similar results. I should also say I don't work for the website or anything like that, I was just desperate to get some drawings done for a (overdue) paper and that's why I used them.

Comment: Freelancers are like boxes of chocolate, you never know what you're going to get.

Comment: @Johannes_B agreed for the most part, but I think an exception can be made for those with many positive reviews (not from spam-bots of course). I'd say the same rules apply for any online transaction -- buyer beware! ;)

Comment: Just updated my answer with my own experience on the website, if the admins feel its too lengthy or has irrelevant content please feel free to edit it.

Comment: That is a really good system i think.

Answer (score 5):

While it would be appreciated here, the proper place on stackoverflow would probably be [careers.sx](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), although that's too expensive for only one job.

TUG has a [jobboard](https://www.tug.org/jobboard.html), though.

Comment: Yeah, my task is much too small for something like careers.sx. I just want someone to give my thesis a final polish with respect to formatting. And the TUG job board doesn't appear to be active.